# Inherit objects. Iterate through all objects

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

Here is my problem:

I have an inherit objects(class) function, which I populate with x many objects, like so:

```
function Booking (doc_id, arrival_date, supplier_amount, client_amount, currency, profit, calculated_profit, currency_rate) {
    this.doc_id = doc_id;
    this.arrival_date = arrival_date;
    this.supplier_amount = supplier_amount;
    this.client_amount = client_amount;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.profit = profit;
    this.calculated_profit = calculated_profit;
    this.exchange_rate = currency_rate;
    if(pastDate(this.arrival_date)) {
        past_date: true;
    }
    else {
        past_date: false;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to iterate through all the objects?
I would like to have a function that iterates through all Booking objects, and uses the results to populate a dataTables table.
I guess the function would have to be defined by

```
Booking.prototype = { }
```

I can´t seem to find anything about this on the web. I have tried all my ideas without success.

Comment: Why don't you pass an object instead of many parameters?

Comment: `Is it possible to iterate through all the objects?` what do you mean by that ? Do you want to iterate through all the properties of that object like doc_id, arrival_date etc..?

Comment: Iterate throught all objects that inherit Booking, and get their properties yes.

Comment: Let me hazard an example guess in pseudocode. `class NightlyBooking extends Booking; class HourlyBooking extends Booking; nb = new NightlyBooking(...); hb = new HourlyBooking(...); hb2 = new HourlyBooking(...)` Is your desired result to iterate through "nb", "hb", and "hb2", no matter where and how they were created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate all `Booking` instances, you must store references to them somewhere:

```js
var Booking = (function() {
    var instances = []; // Array of instances
    function Booking(foo) {
        if (!(this instanceof Booking)) return; // Called without `new`
        instances.push(this); // Store the instance
        this.foo = foo; // Your current code
    }
    Booking.prototype.whatever = function() {
        // You can use `instances` here
    }
    return Booking;
})();
```

But wait: **DO NOT DO THAT** (unless its strictly necessary).

The code above has a big problem: since the `Booking` instances are referenced in `instances`, the garbage collector won't kill them, even if they aren't referenced anywhere else.

Therefore, each time you create an instance, you produce a [**memory leak**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

ECMAScript 6 introduces [`WeakSet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet), which lets you store weakly held objects in a collection, so that the garbage collector will kill them if they aren't referenced anywhere else. But `WeakSet`s aren't iterable, so they aren't useful in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That¨s pretty much the same conclusion I came to.